# Calendar сдвиг времени в другую временную зону

Tags: java, дата, calendar, timezone

Если выполнить код, в консоли будет выведено одинаковое время, хотя текущая зона отличается от установленной в Calendar. Почему так? Ведь вроде время должно быть сдвинуто, тое если сейчас к примеру 10:00 и смещение 2 то во втором случае думал что выведет 12:00.

```
    Date d = new Date();
    System.out.println(d);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);
    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

Метод [`Calendar::getTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--) возвращает экземпляр класса `java.util.Date`, который НЕ содержит никакой информации о часовом поясе, установленном в экземпляре *календаря* :

> The class `Date` represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.
> ...
> ...the Date class is intended to reflect coordinated universal time (UTC)...

Соответственно, при "выводе" экземпляра `Date` при помощи [`Date::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) будет использоваться некий часовой пояс по умолчанию (локальный).

Для управления выводом часового пояса в *старых классах для работы с датой/временем* необходимо использовать `SimpleDateFormat`:

```java
Date d = new Date();
System.out.println(d + "; default tz=" + TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS Z");
System.out.println("formatted with default tz: d=" + sdf.format(d) + "; tz=" + sdf.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
System.out.println("formatted with Pacific tz: d=" + sdf.format(d) + "; tz=" + sdf.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
```

```
Fri Jan 26 17:36:42 EET 2024; default tz=Eastern European Standard Time
formatted with default tz: d=26-01-2024 17:36:920 +0200; tz=Eastern European Standard Time
formatted with Pacific tz: d=26-01-2024 07:36:920 -0800; tz=Pacific Standard Time
```

---

Подход,использующий классы для работы с датой/временем из пакета `java.util` типа `Date, Calendar, TimeZone` и т.п., а также форматирование при помощи `DateFormat / SimpleDateFormat` является устаревшим почти 10 лет со времени выхода Java 8 c обновлённым Java Date/Time API в пакете `java.time`.

Например, существует класс [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), поддерживающий информацию о часовом поясе (в отличие от `LocalDateTime`):

```java
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeDefault = ZonedDateTime.now();
System.out.println("ZonedDateTime (default): " + zonedDateTimeDefault);

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimePacific = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
System.out.println("ZonedDateTime (Pacific): " +zonedDateTimePacific);
```

Вывод будет несколько отличаться от вышеприведённого.

```
ZonedDateTime (default): 2024-01-26T17:45:07.778344200+02:00[Europe/Helsinki]
ZonedDateTime (Pacific): 2024-01-26T07:45:07.780342800-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

---

Что касается дополнительного вопроса *"как можно использовать информацию о часовом поясе в классе `Calendar`"*, то изменение часового пояса повлияет на значение поля, которое возвращается для константы `Calendar.ZONE OFFSET`.

Также эта информация может использоваться в конкретных реализациях календаря типа `GregorianCalendar` для перевода между локальным и GMT часовыми поясами (сам по себе класс `Calendar` является абстрактным):
[Код класса `Calendar` в JDK 8](https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/Calendar.java#L904-L909)

> ```java
> /**
>   * The <code>TimeZone</code> used by this calendar. <code>Calendar</code>
>   * uses the time zone data to translate between locale and GMT time.
>   * @serial
>   */
> private TimeZone        zone;
> ```

К примеру, в классе `GregorianCalendar`, начиная с JDK 8, имеется метод [`GregorianCalendar::toZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#toZonedDateTime--), который позволит получить информацию в корректном часовом поясе:

```java
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
GregorianCalendar gc = (GregorianCalendar) c;
System.out.println(c.getTime() + "; tz=" + c.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
System.out.println("ZONE OFFSET в поясе GMT: " + c.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)/3600_000L);
System.out.println("GregorianCalendar.zonedDateTime GMT: " + gc.toZonedDateTime());

// изменяем часовой пояс
c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
System.out.println("ZONE OFFSET в поясе PST: " + c.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)/3600_000L);
System.out.println("GregorianCalendar.zonedDateTime PST: " + gc.toZonedDateTime());
```

Результат:

```
Sun Jan 28 11:47:03 GMT 2024; tz=Greenwich Mean Time
ZONE OFFSET в поясе GMT: 0
GregorianCalendar.zonedDateTime GMT: 2024-01-28T11:47:03.073Z[GMT]
ZONE OFFSET в поясе PST: -8
GregorianCalendar.zonedDateTime PST: 2024-01-28T03:47:03.073-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

И опять-таки следует подчеркнуть, что класс `Calendar`, его реализации являются *устаревшими* и их не следует использовать в новом коде.

Comment: Чем тогда обусловленно использование метода setTimeZone в экземпляре Calendar? Где и как его можно использовать?

Comment: @JavaJunior, смотрите обновление